# Search all folders for file for "lost, mis-filed " JPG

Tags: directory, search

I have mislaid a particular JPG! is there an program / application  that will search ALL FOLDERS for a particular 2 / 3 letter occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the command `find`, it can search for files and directories on a number of criterias. Something like:

```
find /home \( -name "*.JPG" -or -name "*.jpg" \) -type f -print
```

will look through all of /home and sub-directories for files with extension JPG or jpg. Note that Linux filename are case-sentisive, so you might have to look for other combinations too.

Take a look at 
`man find` in a terminal or google for it, `find` is a swish army knife of possibilities.

Comment: ... you could also use `-iname "*.jpg" -type f -print`